# Doing a task at specific time frequently

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I want to run a program at specific time in every day of every week. how can I do this ?
my OS is ubuntu.
thanks

Answer (score 3):

That's called a crontab. With the command crontab -e you can add a task.

A line in the crontabfile looks like this:

```
*    *    *    *    *  command to be executed
┬    ┬    ┬    ┬    ┬
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    │
│    │    │    │    └───── day of week (0 - 7) (0 or 7 are Sunday, or use names)
│    │    │    └────────── month (1 - 12)
│    │    └─────────────── day of month (1 - 31)
│    └──────────────────── hour (0 - 23)
└───────────────────────── min (0 - 59)
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron

Answer (score 1):

Use cron daemon, to access manual try:

```
man cron
man 5 crontab
```

Comment: if i use cron , my computer automatically to the task that I define for it ?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto) might be an easier read than the `man` page. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

type `crontab -e <enter>` from the command line

And then add an entry with the following format:

```
*     *     *   *    *        command to be executed
-     -     -   -    -
|     |     |   |    |
|     |     |   |    +----- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0)
|     |     |   +------- month (1 - 12)
|     |     +--------- day of        month (1 - 31)
|     +----------- hour (0 - 23)
+------------- min (0 - 59)
```

For example:

```
30   18   *  * *  rm /tmp/*
```

Will execute `rm /tmp/*` every day at 6:30 PM

[More examples here.](http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference)